# Equality of itertools.count in Python

Tags: python, python-itertools

Consider the interactive Python code:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> count(0) == count(0)
False
```

Why is equality not implemented here and defaults to identity? Is this intentional or merely an oversight?

Edit: I did not make myself clear enough. I expected equality to be expressed as the equality of starting points unaware that the current state of the iterator is also being tracked by the `count` object, as pointed out by Martijn Pieters in the comments.

Comment: How did you expect equality to be expressed? Same starting point and current position? You could request for this to be added on the [Python issue tracker](http://bugs.python.org), but there is currently no such feature.

Comment: Didn't realize that iteration state is tracked within the same object. I think I expected count to be an iterable whose `__iter__` method returns a newly created iterator. By that logic equality would simply be defined as the same starting point.

Comment: No, `count()` returns an object with state; a starting point and the current position. But they are deliberately meant to be simple; all they provide is `__iter__` and `next` (`__next__` in Python 3), really.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll make my own iterable with that behaviour then.

Comment: `count` is not merely an iterable. It is an iterator. All iterators are iterable, but some iterables are not iterators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wrap up the helpful comments given by Martijn Pieters and J. F. Sebastian to my question and to close this thereby: `itertools.count` is designed as an iterator and thus tracks its current iteration state. Thereby it is not obvious how equality should be defined.

I wound up wrapping count in the following manner to achieve the behaviour I had expected:

```
import itertools

class count(object):

    def __init__(self, start=0, step=1):
        self.start = start
        self.step = step

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.start == other.start and self.step == other.step

    def __iter__(self):
        return itertools.count(self.start, self.step)
```